# How to correctly write the HTML and CSS for an avatar image with text to the right of it?

Tags: html, css

[image: Resume contact form]

I am unsure how to get the correct HTML and CSS for the bottom part of the resume contact form. When I tried my HTML and CSS, the text would not go to the right of the image. All of the text just goes under the logo box. I am still learning HTML and CSS would like an explanation if possible.

Here is my progress so far:

```css
.resume {
  width: 584px;
  height: 65px;
  font-family: Bitter;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.text {
  width: 699px;
  height: 262px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.logo-box {
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 146px;
  height: 146px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
}

.job {
  width: 561px;
  height: 41px;
  font-family: Bitter;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.company {
  width: 560px;
  height: 53px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.year {
  width: 418px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.show-more {
  width: 181px;
  height: 19px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #92719e;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">My Resume</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum . . . </div>
<div class="logo-box">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="job">Director of Web Development</div>
<div class="company">ABCD Company</div>
<div class="year">1999 - 2010</div>
<div class="show-more">SHOW MORE</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` property via wrapping your `logo` div and rest of the `content`

You can see below example it may helps you.

```css
.resume {
  width: 584px;
  height: 65px;
  font-family: Bitter;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.text {
  width: 699px;
  height: 262px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.logo-box {
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 146px;
  height: 146px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
}

.job {
  width: 561px;
  height: 41px;
  font-family: Bitter;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.company {
  width: 560px;
  height: 53px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.year {
  width: 418px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #575159;
}

.show-more {
  width: 181px;
  height: 19px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #92719e;
}
.flex-wrap {
 display: flex;
}
.flex-wrap .content {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">My Resume</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum . . . </div>
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="logo-box">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="job">Director of Web Development</div>
    <div class="company">ABCD Company</div>
    <div class="year">1999 - 2010</div>
    <div class="show-more">SHOW MORE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid allows you to manage your layout in a more efficient way than other CSS layout solutions. It is properly based on the fact that your HTML should stay logical to what you see and then you're not forced to create multiple element only destined to layout building. You could write everything about it just [there](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

- `grid-template-columns` property define the width of each column
- `grid-column-gap` property define the gap between the columns

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed risus ligula, semper nec pretium nec.  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many options. One is to use `display: flex` as parent and inside two child doms: one for text, other for image. Also you can use table cells for that. Also it can be done with floats, but i prefer cell or flex logic, cause you can center contents vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.resume {
    width: 584px;
    height: 65px;
    font-family: Bitter;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.text {
    width: 699px;
    height: 262px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.logo-box {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.logo {
    width: 146px;
    height: 146px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border: solid 1px #979797;
}

.job {
    width: 561px;
    height: 41px;
    font-family: Bitter;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.company {
    width: 560px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.year {
    width: 418px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.show-more {
    width: 181px;
    height: 19px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #92719e;
}
.flex_item
{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">My Resume</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum . . . </div>
<div class="flex_item">
<div class="logo-box">
     <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-details">
  <div class="job">Director of Web Development</div>
  <div class="company">ABCD Company</div>
  <div class="year">1999 - 2010</div>
  <div class="show-more">SHOW MORE</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use another way for flex property